# Remoção de linhas com 'rowspan' dinâmicos em tabela

Tags: javascript, html, table

Possuo um elemento `<table>` ao qual insiro linhas com `<td>` cujo `rowspan` varia de acordo com o valor inserido no `input`. Gostaria de remover linhas no clique do botão <kbd>Remove rows</kbd> de acordo com o `radioButton` selecionado.

Segue o código funcionando:

```js
function addLines(){
  tabBody=document.getElementById("myTable");
  qtdRowsInput = document.getElementById("qtdRows").value;

  var valueRadioButton = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < qtdRowsInput; i++) {
    row=document.createElement("tr");
           
    if(i == 0){
      var tdElement0 = document.createElement("td");
      tdElement0.rowSpan = qtdRowsInput;
    }

    var tdElement1 = document.createElement("td");
    var tdElement2 = document.createElement("td");
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "radio";
    checkbox.name = "radioButton";
    checkbox.value = valueRadioButton;
    checkbox.id = "rdb"+valueRadioButton;

    textnode1=document.createTextNode(qtdRowsInput);  
    textnode2=document.createTextNode("A");

    if(i == 0){
      tdElement0.appendChild(checkbox);
    }

    tdElement1.appendChild(textnode1);
    tdElement2.appendChild(textnode2);

    if(i == 0){
      row.appendChild(tdElement0);
    }
    row.appendChild(tdElement1);
    row.appendChild(tdElement2);
    tabBody.appendChild(row);
  }

  valueRadioButton++;
}

function removeRows(){

}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
Rows: <input type="number" id="qtdRows" min="1"/> <button onclick="addLines();">Add rows</button> <button onclick="removeRows();">Remove rows</button>  <br> <br>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>X</th>
    <th>Numbers</th>
    <th>Letters</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: *Downvoter* há algo de errado com a pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso, precisa realizar 3 etapas:

- Identificar o radio selecionado
- Obter índices em relação ao elemento pai de cada linha
- Remover as linhas

O código ficaria:

```
var radio = document.querySelector('[name=radioButton]:checked');
if (radio) {
  var cell = radio.parentElement;
  var row = cell.parentElement;
  var tableChildren = row.parentElement.children;
  var index = Array.from(tableChildren).indexOf(row);
  var limit = index + parseInt(cell.rowSpan);
  while (limit-- > index) {
    tableChildren[limit].remove()
  }
}
```

Verifique no *snippet* abaixo o código funcionando:

```js
function addLines(){
  tabBody=document.getElementById("myTable");
  qtdRowsInput = document.getElementById("qtdRows").value;

  var valueRadioButton = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < qtdRowsInput; i++) {
    row=document.createElement("tr");
             
    if(i == 0){
      var tdElement0 = document.createElement("td");
      tdElement0.rowSpan = qtdRowsInput;
    }

    var tdElement1 = document.createElement("td");
    var tdElement2 = document.createElement("td");
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "radio";
    checkbox.name = "radioButton";
    checkbox.value = valueRadioButton;
    checkbox.id = "rdb"+valueRadioButton;

    textnode1=document.createTextNode(qtdRowsInput);  
    textnode2=document.createTextNode("A");

    if(i == 0){
      tdElement0.appendChild(checkbox);
    }

    tdElement1.appendChild(textnode1);
    tdElement2.appendChild(textnode2);

    if(i == 0){
      row.appendChild(tdElement0);
    }
    row.appendChild(tdElement1);
    row.appendChild(tdElement2);
    tabBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  valueRadioButton++;
}

function removeRows(){
  var radio = document.querySelector('[name=radioButton]:checked');
  if (radio) {
    var cell = radio.parentElement;
    var row = cell.parentElement;
    var tableChildren = row.parentElement.children;
    var index = Array.from(tableChildren).indexOf(row);
    var limit = index + parseInt(cell.rowSpan);
    while (limit-- > index) {
      tableChildren[limit].remove()
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
Rows: <input type="number" id="qtdRows" min="1" value="1"/>
<button onclick="addLines();">Add rows</button>
<button onclick="removeRows();">Remove rows</button>
<br><br>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>X</th>
    <th>Numbers</th>
    <th>Letters</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Quase nunca vejo a utilização do `indexOf` comparando os objetos pela própria referência. Legal! +1 :) A única ressalva que posso pensar é que pode ser um pouco (quase nada) menos eficiente a depender do tamanho da lista de elementos.

Answer (score 1):

Uma vez que o usuário clique no botão de remover as linhas selecionadas, precisam ser realizadas algumas etapas.

Primeiro, queremos obter o elemento que o usuário selecionou. Para isso, fazemos algo como:

```
const input = document.querySelector('#myTable [name="radioButton"]:checked');
```

Isso retornará, dentro dos limites selecionáveis de `#myTable`, o campo cujo `name` seja igual a `radioButton` e que foi marcado pelo usuário.

Tendo selecionado o elemento, precisamos determinar o `rowspan` relacionado a ele. Em posse do `rowspan` numérico de valor N, basta selecionar as N - 1 linhas após a atual (incluindo a atual).

Em seguida basta remover todos os elementos selecionados.

Juntando tudo, teremos algo como:

```
function removeRows() {
  const input = document.querySelector('#myTable [name="radioButton"]:checked');

  // Garante que o código abaixo não seja executado caso nenhum elemento seja selecionado:
  if (!input) return;

  const td = input.parentElement;
  const { rowSpan } = td; // A célula possui atributo numérico `rowSpan`.

  // Ascendemos mais uma vez na árvore para obter a linha atual:
  const tr = td.parentElement;

  // Obtemos a lista das linhas a serem removidas:
  const rowsToRemove = getNextNElements(tr, rowSpan - 1);

  for (const row of rowsToRemove) {
    row.remove();
  }
}
```

Note que a função `getNextNElements` não é *nativa* dos navegadores. Portanto, precisamos implementá-la de algum modo. Uma possibilidade seria algo como:

```
/**
 * Seleciona o elemento e os próximos N.
 *
 * @param {HTMLElement} current
 * @param {number} n
 * @return {Array<HTMLElement>}
 */
function getNextNElements(current, n) {
  const list = [current];

  while (n-- > 0) {
    const last = list[list.length - 1];
    list.push(last?.nextElementSibling ?? null);
  }

  return list;
}
```

Ela basicamente pega um filho N de determinado elemento e cria uma lista com o elemento atual e os próximos `n` (passado via 2º argumento). A vantagem de utilizar esse tipo de função é que não é necessário varrer toda a lista de elementos (que *pode* ser extensa) para determinar o índice do *primeiro* elemento a ser removido.

O encadeamento opcional `?.` e operador de coalescência nula foram utilizados caso `n` seja maior que o número de elementos restantes. Assim evitam-se erros relacionados à tentativa de acesso a alguma propriedade de `null`. [Saiba mais aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/486355/69296)

Teremos, enfim, algo assim:

```js
function addLines() {
  tabBody = document.getElementById('myTable');
  qtdRowsInput = document.getElementById('qtdRows').value;

  var valueRadioButton = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < qtdRowsInput; i++) {
    row = document.createElement('tr');

    if (i == 0) {
      var tdElement0 = document.createElement('td');
      tdElement0.rowSpan = qtdRowsInput;
    }

    var tdElement1 = document.createElement('td');
    var tdElement2 = document.createElement('td');
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = 'radio';
    checkbox.name = 'radioButton';
    checkbox.value = valueRadioButton;
    checkbox.id = 'rdb' + valueRadioButton;

    textnode1 = document.createTextNode(qtdRowsInput);
    textnode2 = document.createTextNode('A');

    if (i == 0) {
      tdElement0.appendChild(checkbox);
    }

    tdElement1.appendChild(textnode1);
    tdElement2.appendChild(textnode2);

    if (i == 0) {
      row.appendChild(tdElement0);
    }
    row.appendChild(tdElement1);
    row.appendChild(tdElement2);
    tabBody.appendChild(row);
  }

  valueRadioButton++;
}

function removeRows() {
  const input = document.querySelector('#myTable [name="radioButton"]:checked');

  // Garante que o código abaixo não seja executado caso nenhum elemento seja selecionado:
  if (!input) return;

  const td = input.parentElement;
  const { rowSpan } = td; // A célula possui atributo numérico `rowSpan`.

  // Ascendemos mais uma vez na árvore para obter a linha atual:
  const tr = td.parentElement;

  // Obtemos a lista das linhas a serem removidas:
  const rowsToRemove = getNextNElements(tr, rowSpan - 1);

  for (const row of rowsToRemove) {
    row.remove();
  }
}

/**
 * Seleciona o elemento e os próximos N.
 *
 * @param {HTMLElement} current
 * @param {number} n
 * @return {Array<HTMLElement>}
 */
function getNextNElements(current, n) {
  const list = [current];

  while (n-- > 0) {
    const last = list[list.length - 1];
    list.push(last?.nextElementSibling ?? null);
  }

  return list;
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
Rows: <input type="number" id="qtdRows" min="1"/> <button onclick="addLines();">Add rows</button> <button onclick="removeRows();">Remove rows</button>  <br> <br>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th> X </th>
    <th> Numbers</th>
    <th> Letters</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

<sup><sup>Escondido para não ocupar muito espaço desnecessariamente.</sup></sup>