# O que significa uma interrogação "?." no acesso às propriedades de um objeto?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, operadores

Já utilizei operadores ternário para fazer este tipo de verificação:

```
route.params.userUpdated ? route.params.userUpdated : undefined;
```

Mas nunca tinha visto algo assim:

```
route.params?.userUpdated;
```

O que exatamente faz esse `?.`?

Comment: Segue a DOC 
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 23):

Chama-se [encadeamento opcional](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (*optional chaining*). Foi introduzido no ECMAScript 2020.

É análogo ao operador `.`, de modo que te permite acessar propriedades de objetos. A diferença é que não vai lançar um erro se você tentar acessar uma [propriedade *nullish*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/nullish) (`null` ou `undefined`).

Veja a diferença:

```js
const obj = {
  person: {
    name: 'Foo',
    age: 50
  }
};

console.log(obj.person?.name); //=> Foo
console.log(obj.person.name); //=> Foo

console.log(obj.undefinedProp?.foo); //=> undefined
console.log(obj.undefinedProp.foo); //=> BOM! TypeError
```

---

Mas não se limita ao “acesso estático”. Você pode utilizá-lo em várias situações:

#### Acessar propriedades de objeto (análogo à notação ponto)

Já vimos este exemplo anteriormente. A sintaxe é esta:

```
obj.val?.prop
```

Desse modo, se `val` for `null` ou `undefined`, o código não lançará um `TypeError`. A expressão simplesmente avaliará para `undefined`. Se `val` for um objeto, o acesso ocorrerá normalmente, comparável a utilizar o `.`.

#### Acessar propriedades de objeto dinamicamente (análogo à notação de colchete)

A sintaxe é esta:

```
obj.val?.[expr]
obj.arr?.[index]
```

É similar ao anterior, mas se utiliza o colchete para procurar por uma chave “dinâmica” — resultado de uma expressão. Pode utilizar símbolos ou números também.

O funcionamento é o mesmo — se o objeto que se tenta acessar for *nullish*, a expressão retornará `undefined` ao invés de lançar o erro. Caso contrário, a propriedade será procurada por chave resultante da expressão dentro dos colchetes normalmente. Você também pode utilizar isso para tentar acessar um índice de um possível array. Se for nulo e você estiver usando o encadeamento opcional nenhum erro será lançado.

Exemplos:

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(obj?.['b']); //=> 2
console.log(arr?.[2]); //=> 3

console.log(obj.null?.['prop']); //=> undefined
console.log(obj.undefinedArr?.[0]); //=> undefined
```

#### Aplicar função opcionalmente

A sintaxe é esta:

```
obj.func?.(args)
```

Nesse caso, se `obj.func` for uma função, será chamada normalmente. Se `obj.func` for *nullish*, a aplicação não ocorrerá e a expressão retornará `undefined`.

Tome cuidado com este cenário: A “aplicação opcional” só ocorrerá se `obj.func` for *nullish*. Se for algum valor (não *nullish*) que não implemente `[[Call]]` (isto é, não pode ser chamado como uma função), você receberá um `TypeError`, uma vez que tentou chamar um valor que não é função.

Exemplos:

```js
const obj = {
  fn: function() {
    return 5;
  },
  
  str: 'Hello'
};

console.log(obj.fn?.()); //=> 5
console.log(obj.undefinedFn?.()); //=> undefined
console.log(obj.str?.()); //=> BOM! TypeError
```

---

### Adendo: Operador de coalescência nula

Como o encadeamento opcional garante que nenhum erro será lançado mediante simples acessos a propriedades de objeto, casa extremamente bem com o [operador de de coalescência nula](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/operador_de_coalescencia_nula) (`??`), que também foi introduzido no ES2020.

Ele realiza um curto-circuito somente se o primeiro operando for `null` ou `undefined` (os possíveis resultados do encadeamento opcional "falho"):

```js
const obj = {
  foo: {
    qux: false
  }
};

console.log(obj.foo?.bar?.baz ?? 'Valor padrão'); //=> Valor padrão
console.log(obj.foo?.qux ?? 'Valor padrão'); //=> false
```

Comment: Conhecia do TypeScript, não sabia que já havia chego ao ECMAScript

Comment: Baita aula kk. Vlw