# Dúvida referente ao optional chaining

Tags: javascript

Dando uma olhada em alguns códigos pela web me deparei com o seguinte trecho:

```js
let userAdmin = {
  admin() {
    alert("I am admin");
  }
};

let userGuest = {};

userAdmin.admin?.(); // I am admin

userGuest.admin?.(); // nothing happens (no such method)
```

Entendi o por quê só foi disparado o alert com a mensagem **I am admin**, pois em `userGuest` foi declarado um objeto vazio. Mas me surgiram duas indagações:

- 1ª - Por que depois de `admin?` foi dado um ponto e depois os parênteses, seria a sintaxe para poder fazer a utilização do **`optional chaining`** no método ou é outra coisa?
- 2ª - No caso da declaração `userGuest.admin?.()` me parece um desperdício de recurso, não seria melhor verificar se o objeto possui algo dentro primeiro, algo como `if (userGuest !== {})`?

Espero que as dúvidas tenham ficadas claras!  Os exemplos foram retirados deste [link](https://javascript.info/optional-chaining#other-variants).

Comment: Por que acha que em (2) o *optional chaining* seria um desperdício de recurso?

Comment: Opa Woss, então é o que acho mas não tenho certeza não :). Pq pela lógica agente está tentando executar algo dentro de uma coisa que está vazia, não seria mais viável testar se algo está vazio primeiro? Tipo como comentei `if (userGuest !== {})` ou com um próprio optional chaining `userGuest?.admin`?

Comment: Só pra constar, `userGuest !== {}` sempre será `true`, pois a comparação verifica se os objetos são o mesmo (e nunca serão, porque `{}` cria um novo objeto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mais informações, ler: [O que significa uma interrogação "?." no acesso às propriedades de um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/486355/5878)

> 1ª - Por que depois de `admin?` foi dado um ponto e depois os parênteses, seria a sintaxe para poder fazer a utilização do optional chaining no método ou é outra coisa?

Simplesmente porque a sintaxe do operador de encadeamento opcional é o `?.`, não existe o `?` sozinho. Por mais besta que possa parecer, seria o mesmo que questionar porque foi feito `x++` para utilizar o operador de auto incremento.

> 2ª - No caso da declaração `userGuest.admin?.()` me parece um desperdício de recurso, não seria melhor verificar se o objeto possui algo dentro primeiro, algo como `if (userGuest !== {})`?

O operador de encadeamento opcional é justamente para isso. Ao ler na documentação e na resposta citada verá que o JS interrompe a avaliação daquela expressão quando o operando que o antecede é `undefined` ou `null`, retornando `undefined` independente do que está a direita dele.

Em outras palavras, fazer algo como `user?.admin?.()` seria o equivalente a:

```js
if (user === undefined) {
  return undefined;
}

if (user.admin === undefined) {
  return undefined;
}

return user.admin();
```

Mas perceba que ele só valida se o operando é diferente de `undefined` ou `null`, não validando se o atributo é chamável ou não. Se o campo existir e ser uma string, por exemplo, ainda dará erro `TypeError`, mesmo usando o operador de encadeamento opcional.

```js
let userAdmin = {
  admin: 'sou uma string'
};


userAdmin.admin?.();
```

Comment: Blza man, obrigado pela resposta.